# jQuery tablesorter display all th elements in a column

Tags: jquery, css, tablesorter

Tablesorter is working fine, but all th elements are displayed in a column one under another instead of normal way of displaying in a row. Only IE display them right :)

Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/cmMvF/2/

When I remove tablesorter script, table is displayed correct. I have no additional classes on tables except tablesorter demo blue theme. My table head part is simple:

```
<table id='catalog_model_line' width='100%' class='tablesorter'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="header headerSortDown">Модельный ряд</th>
        <th class="header">Кузов</th>
        <th class="header">Дата выпуска</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
..................
```

What to do in such situation?

Comment: please create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates problem, page link repeatedly times out and at some time will likely not show the same problem for future readers of this post

Comment: Updated my question with link. I am new to Fiddle and I didn't know what it was made for, but now I do. Thanks!

Comment: problem is tablesorter adds class `header` to `TH`. This conflicts with your main page css rule for `.header` that sets width to `100%`. Can see this quickly in browser console. Adding rule for `.tablesorter .header` should fix it

Comment: Yes, it really is. I have forgotted about that class at all... Now I'm a little ashamed of my question)) Thanks a lot, why haven't you wrote it like an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem is tablesorter adds class `header` to `TH`. This conflicts with your main page css rule for `.header` that sets width to 100%. Can see this quickly in browser console. Adding rule for `.tablesorter .header` should fix it

Comment: +1: Or, you can change the class added to the `TH` by modifying tablesorter's `cssHeader` option; but then you would have to change tablesorter's css file.

Comment: @Mottie actually I tried that, it adds an extra class that you define but keeps the same `header` class. Either way have to write more specific rule.